# How to Iterate only directly set enum values in plain c?

Tags: c, enums

I have an `enum` defined in plain c like so:

```c
typedef enum {
    // Determine position of Red and Green color:
    // RED[2:0], GREEN[5:3], BLUE implicitly. Thus, [7:6]==!0
    LED_BO_RedGreenBlue=0b00010001,
    LED_BO_RedBlueGreen=0b00100001,
    LED_BO_GreenBlueRed=0b00001100,
    LED_BO_GreenRedBlue=0b00001010,
    LED_BO_BlueRedGreen=0b00100010,
    LED_BO_BlueGreenRed=0b00010100,
} led_byteorder_values_t;
```

Unfortuantely, the only way I have come up with to check if a given `uint8_t` has a value defined explicitly in this enum is this:

```c
uint8_t byteToTest = 0; // has invalid value, so /default/ path will be taken.
switch (byteToTest) {
    case: LED_BO_RedGreenBlue: break;
    case: LED_BO_RedBlueGreen: break;
    case: LED_BO_GreenBlueRed: break;
    case: LED_BO_GreenRedBlue: break;
    case: LED_BO_BlueRedGreen: break;
    case: LED_BO_BlueGreenRed: break;
    default: byteToTest = LED_BO_RedGreenBlue; break;
}
```

Is there a better / shorter way to test a variable against arbitrary values, possibly without having to define an additional `const [...]`?

Comment: There is built-in no way in the language. It isn't uncommon to preload a fixed array via initializer at program startup with the enum values in order, then looping over *that*. A pain to maintain, but effective.

Comment: Note that using the `0b` notation for binary is not strictly portable; it is not a part of Standard C.  WhozCraig's suggestion of an array in sorted order determined in the source code is one way to do it; another is to sort the array at runtime (which can be more reliable than depending on the source code being correct).

Comment: Alright, thanks to both of you. Will @WhozCraig create an answer? I'd like to accept his suggestion, since sorting at runtime is out of scope for my embedded programming requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though the attractiveness of the following alternative isn't heartwarming, it is none-the-less likely effective for the platform you're currently using.

The language doesn't support enumeration of `enum` values as a built-in construct. There are ways to "fake" it though. Once such way is by providing your own table-of-enum, then enumerating *that*. I will argue, however, whether this is "better". Easier to type, yes. Logical, maybe. but your switch statement is most-assuredly going to compile down to more efficient code. I would be shocked if it didn't.

```
typedef enum {
    // Determine position of Red and Green color:
    // RED[2:0], GREEN[5:3], BLUE implicitly. Thus, [7:6]==!0
    LED_BO_RedGreenBlue=0b00010001,
    LED_BO_RedBlueGreen=0b00100001,
    LED_BO_GreenBlueRed=0b00001100,
    LED_BO_GreenRedBlue=0b00001010,
    LED_BO_BlueRedGreen=0b00100010,
    LED_BO_BlueGreenRed=0b00010100,
} led_byteorder_values_t;

static const led_byteorder_values_t led_byteorder_values[] = 
{
    LED_BO_RedGreenBlue,
    LED_BO_RedBlueGreen,
    LED_BO_GreenBlueRed,
    LED_BO_GreenRedBlue,
    LED_BO_BlueRedGreen,
    LED_BO_BlueGreenRed
};

static const size_t size_led_byteorder_values = 
    sizeof(led_byteorder_values)/sizeof(*led_byteorder_values);
```

With that you can enumerate the values directly via a `[0...size_led_byteorder_values)` loop. you can still custom-order the loop by adjusting the table entry order for most-to-least-likely hit for quicker loop-exit. But again, it isn't like that isn't possible with a decently formed switch such as yours.

Anyway, its a thought, and I feel your pain. Its one of the few features that not-just-C++, but *most* languages don't offer, and it certainly seems to pop up as useful once in awhile.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You may define enum like below.

```
typedef enum : uint8_t { // see this type, it's a better defintion
    // Determine position of Red and Green color:
    // RED[2:0], GREEN[5:3], BLUE implicitly. Thus, [7:6]==!0
    LED_BO_RedGreenBlue=0b00010001,
    ........

} led_byteorder_values_t;
```

Comment: Hm, tried that a moment ago, compiler (avr-gcc) throws an error "expected '{' before token ':'", I realize that I can use a byte array, but I wanted to avoid that.